# EXIF (or other meta-data) data that Windows displays but PHP does not

Tags: php, exif

I am working to pull some information from JPEGs supplied to my client by a photographer.

When examined under Windows all of the images contain data in a field called Tags:

[image]

[image]

To do some testing first I made the following script and am iterating over entries in the binary file headers using the code below.

Sometimes I get values for ImageDescription.  Often text in Copyright and Author but the Tags content never ever shows up here and it is the capture of that content the client most wants to automate.

Can anyone advise me as to how I can access the Tags field content?

Uploaded copy of file is [here](http://nolaflash.com/stackoverflow/ANI_69.jpg).

**UPDATE** - changed IDF0 to ANY_TAG and added 3rd arg **true** to exif_read_data() per Tiger-222's response.  Also added print_r output at end of post

**UPDATE 2** Added requested error_display() and ini_set() calls and also tried exif_read_data() 2nd arg of 0 in place of 'ANY_TAG' per https://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('exif.encode_unicode', 'UTF-8');  // To see WINXP values
    error_reporting(-1);        
    $n = (intval($_GET['n'])) ? $_GET['n'] : 99;
    echo "ANI_$n.jpg:<br />\n";
    $exif = exif_read_data("ANI_$n.jpg", 'ANY_TAG', true);
    echo $exif===false ? "No header data found.<br />\n" : "Image contains the following headers:<br><br />\n";

    if ($exif) {
        foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
            if (is_array($section)) {
                foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
                    echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
                }
            } else {
                echo "$key: $section<br>\n";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

The following is the content dumped by the script for the whooping crane image:

```
ANI_69.jpg:
Image contains the following headers:

FileName: ANI_69.jpg
FileDateTime: 1428255617
FileSize: 2448245
FileType: 2
MimeType: image/jpeg
SectionsFound: ANY_TAG, IFD0, THUMBNAIL, EXIF
COMPUTED.html: width="1798" height="2697"
COMPUTED.Height: 2697
COMPUTED.Width: 1798
COMPUTED.IsColor: 1
COMPUTED.ByteOrderMotorola: 0
COMPUTED.Copyright: Photographer name here
COMPUTED.Thumbnail.FileType: 2
COMPUTED.Thumbnail.MimeType: image/jpeg
ImageWidth: 1798
ImageLength: 2697
BitsPerSample.0: 8
BitsPerSample.1: 8
BitsPerSample.2: 8
PhotometricInterpretation: 2
Orientation: 1
SamplesPerPixel: 3
XResolution: 1000000/10000
YResolution: 1000000/10000
ResolutionUnit: 2
Software: Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Macintosh)
DateTime: 2014:12:28 19:17:36
Artist: Photographer name here
Copyright: Photographer name here
Exif_IFD_Pointer: 316
THUMBNAIL.Compression: 6
THUMBNAIL.XResolution: 72/1
THUMBNAIL.YResolution: 72/1
THUMBNAIL.ResolutionUnit: 2
THUMBNAIL.JPEGInterchangeFormat: 554
THUMBNAIL.JPEGInterchangeFormatLength: 3211
ExifVersion: 0230
DateTimeOriginal: 2014:11:03 11:14:27
DateTimeDigitized: 2014:11:03 11:14:27
SubSecTimeOriginal: 76
SubSecTimeDigitized: 76
ColorSpace: 65535
ExifImageWidth: 1798
ExifImageLength: 2697
```

Here's a dump of $exif from `$exif = exif_read_data("ANI_$n.jpg", 'ANY_TAG', true);`

```
Array
(
    [FILE] => Array
        (
            [FileName] => ANI_69.jpg
            [FileDateTime] => 1428255617
            [FileSize] => 2448245
            [FileType] => 2
            [MimeType] => image/jpeg
            [SectionsFound] => ANY_TAG, IFD0, THUMBNAIL, EXIF
        )

    [COMPUTED] => Array
        (
            [html] => width="1798" height="2697"
            [Height] => 2697
            [Width] => 1798
            [IsColor] => 1
            [ByteOrderMotorola] => 0
            [Copyright] => Digital Roux Photography LLC
            [Thumbnail.FileType] => 2
            [Thumbnail.MimeType] => image/jpeg
        )

    [IFD0] => Array
        (
            [ImageWidth] => 1798
            [ImageLength] => 2697
            [BitsPerSample] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 8
                    [1] => 8
                    [2] => 8
                )

            [PhotometricInterpretation] => 2
            [Orientation] => 1
            [SamplesPerPixel] => 3
            [XResolution] => 1000000/10000
            [YResolution] => 1000000/10000
            [ResolutionUnit] => 2
            [Software] => Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Macintosh)
            [DateTime] => 2014:12:28 19:17:36
            [Artist] => Digital Roux Photography LLC
            [Copyright] => Digital Roux Photography LLC
            [Exif_IFD_Pointer] => 316
        )

    [THUMBNAIL] => Array
        (
            [Compression] => 6
            [XResolution] => 72/1
            [YResolution] => 72/1
            [ResolutionUnit] => 2
            [JPEGInterchangeFormat] => 554
            [JPEGInterchangeFormatLength] => 3211
        )

    [EXIF] => Array
        (
            [ExifVersion] => 0230
            [DateTimeOriginal] => 2014:11:03 11:14:27
            [DateTimeDigitized] => 2014:11:03 11:14:27
            [SubSecTimeOriginal] => 76
            [SubSecTimeDigitized] => 76
            [ColorSpace] => 65535
            [ExifImageWidth] => 1798
            [ExifImageLength] => 2697
        )

)
```

[image]

Comment: afair these tags are not stored inside of jpg, windows has its own database for them

Comment: @Lashane have added screenshot showing the tags in the binary code.  All of these come to me in bulk with the tags in them; my local Windows would have no way of adding them...

Comment: Could you attach the picture for tests please?

Comment: @Tiger-222 sure can, thank you!  http://nolaflash.com/stackoverflow/ANI_69.jpg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In **three** points (thanks to jerrygarciuh for his patience and help).

**1)** To see extra informations, just pass the third argument to `true`:

```
$exif = exif_read_data("ANI_$n.jpg", 'IFD0', true);
```

As explained [here](https://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php), it will force the conversion to an array to avoid conflicts between sections. You will find Tags under the `IFD0.Keywords` keyword.

**2)** [There is an issue](https://php.net/manual/fr/function.exif-read-data.php#73645) with `WINXP.Keywords`. To display correctly these informations, just set the encoding to UFT-8:

```
ini_set('exif.encode_unicode', 'UTF-8');
```

**3)** Thanks to [this question from Ferdy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053383/how-to-read-lightroom-keywords-from-image-file-using-php), extra informations setted by Lightroom could be read using [iptcparse](https://php.net/manual/fr/function.iptcparse.php). This is the full script:

```
ini_set('exif.encode_unicode', 'UTF-8');  // To see WINXP values

// Exif informations -- limited by PHP
$exif = exif_read_data("ANI_$n.jpg", 'ANY_TAG', true);
print_r($exif);

// Additionnal informations from Lightroom
getimagesize("ANI_$n.jpg", $infos);
if ( isset($infos['APP13']) ) {
    print_r(iptcparse($infos['APP13']));
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [FILE] => Array
        (
            [FileName] => ANI_69.or.jpg
            [FileDateTime] => 1431382165
            [FileSize] => 2450950
            [FileType] => 2
            [MimeType] => image/jpeg
            [SectionsFound] => ANY_TAG, IFD0, THUMBNAIL, EXIF, WINXP
        )

    [COMPUTED] => Array
        (
            [html] => width="1798" height="2697"
            [Height] => 2697
            [Width] => 1798
            [IsColor] => 1
            [ByteOrderMotorola] => 1
            [Copyright] => Digital Roux Photography LLC
            [Thumbnail.FileType] => 2
            [Thumbnail.MimeType] => image/jpeg
        )

    [IFD0] => Array
        (
            [ImageWidth] => 1798
            [ImageLength] => 2697
            [BitsPerSample] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 8
                    [1] => 8
                    [2] => 8
                )

            [PhotometricInterpretation] => 2
            [ImageDescription] => Rusty Costanza / Digital Roux Photography
            [Orientation] => 1
            [SamplesPerPixel] => 3
            [XResolution] => 1000000/10000
            [YResolution] => 1000000/10000
            [ResolutionUnit] => 2
            [Software] => Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Macintosh)
            [DateTime] => 2014:12:28 19:17:36
            [Artist] => Digital Roux Photography LLC
            [Copyright] => Digital Roux Photography LLC
            [Exif_IFD_Pointer] => 2468
            [Title] => Rusty Costanza / Digital Roux Photography
            [Keywords] => whooping crane
            [UndefinedTag:0xEA1C] => �
        )

    [THUMBNAIL] => Array
        (
            [Compression] => 6
            [XResolution] => 72/1
            [YResolution] => 72/1
            [ResolutionUnit] => 2
            [JPEGInterchangeFormat] => 4894
            [JPEGInterchangeFormatLength] => 3371
        )

    [EXIF] => Array
        (
            [ExifVersion] => 0230
            [DateTimeOriginal] => 2014:11:03 11:14:27
            [DateTimeDigitized] => 2014:11:03 11:14:27
            [SubSecTimeOriginal] => 76
            [SubSecTimeDigitized] => 76
            [ColorSpace] => 65535
            [ExifImageWidth] => 1798
            [ExifImageLength] => 2697
            [UndefinedTag:0xEA1C] => �
        )

    [WINXP] => Array
        (
            [Title] => 刀甀猀琀礀 䌀漀猀琀愀渀稀愀 ⼀ 䐀椀最椀琀愀氀 刀漀甀砀 倀栀漀琀漀最爀愀瀀栀礀ഀ
            [Keywords] => 眀栀漀漀瀀椀渀最 挀爀愀渀攀
        )
)

Array
(
    [1#090] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [2#000] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [2#055] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20141103
        )

    [2#060] => Array
        (
            [0] => 111427+0000
        )

    [2#090] => Array
        (
            [0] => New Orleans
        )

    [2#025] => Array
        (
            [0] => whooping crane
        )

    [2#080] => Array
        (
            [0] => Digital Roux Photography LLC
        )

    [2#120] => Array
        (
            [0] => Rusty Costanza / Digital Roux Photography
        )

    [2#116] => Array
        (
            [0] => Digital Roux Photography LLC
        )

    [2#221] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0:0:0:-00001
        )

    [2#062] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20141103
        )
)
```

By the way, nice picture ;)

Comment: Thank you!  Maybe I have exif_read_data() version issues.  When implemented the only output get is `
ANI_69.jpg:<br />
Image contains the following headers:<br><br />
ImageWidth: 1798
ImageLength: 2697
0: 8
1: 8
2: 8
PhotometricInterpretation: 2
Orientation: 1
SamplesPerPixel: 3
XResolution: 1000000/10000
YResolution: 1000000/10000
ResolutionUnit: 2
Software: Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Macintosh)
DateTime: 2014:12:28 19:17:36
Artist: Photographer name here
Copyright: Photographer name here
Exif_IFD_Pointer: 316`

Comment: The `Exif_IFD_Pointer` should be the same as I get ... Could you display errors and warnings like I did?

Comment: I added `error_reporting(E_ALL)` just now but no change in output.  Also not seeing WinXP or any entry for keywords in output.  Dump of $exif added to post.

Comment: Also now changed to `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);`  but no change in output

Comment: Added all of these now but output is unchanged  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('exif.encode_unicode', 'UTF-8');  // To see WINXP values
error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: I added infos about needed modules. Could you check yours? Perhaps you do not have an up to date version of exif or no mbstring module at all.

Comment: Added screen cap of the mbstring and exif sections of phpinfo() called from foot of file

Comment: Well, I am starting to be out of ideas. On which OS are you executing the script?

Comment: uname -a output: Linux ps29943 3.1.9-vs2.3.2.5vs2.3.2.5+ #3 SMP Wed Feb 12 13:51:29 PST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77561/discussion-between-tiger-222-and-jerrygarciuh).

Comment: Tiger-222 went so far above and beyond I am humbled by his generosity and kindness!

Comment: I will award the bounty to you as soon as SO allows me to

Comment: Hi @Tiger-222, do you have any idea why `ini_set('exif.encode_unicode', 'UTF-8')` didn't work for me? I have problem with encoding, in meta data I have some latin, but php displays some  instead of special characters.